# Хэширование таблиц

Tags: алгоритм

XOR со сдвигом.

> Одним из простейших примеров хэш-функции является побитный XOR каждого блока (ASCII значение в двоичной системе счисления). Часто при использовании подобного метода для каждого блока выполняется однобитный циклический сдвиг после вычисления хэш-кода. Это можно описать следующим образом.
>
> - Установить n-битный хэш-код в ноль.
> - Для каждого n-битного блока данных выполнить следующие операции:
> - сдвинуть циклически текущий хэш-код влево на один бит;
> - выполнить операцию XOR для очередного блока и хэш-кода.
>
> Это даст эффект "случайности" входа и уничтожит любую регулярность, которая присутствует во входных значениях.

Что мне надо сделать? Какие операции?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если Block -- массив, содержащий данные блока, а BlockSize -- размер блока (число элементов в массиве), то этот алгоритм (хэш вычисляется в переменной HashCode, случай n=8*SizeOf(Block[0])) реализуется так:

```
// pascal
HashCode := 0;
for I := 0 to BlockSize - 1 do
    HashCode := (HashCode shl 1) xor Block[I]; 
// C
hashCode = 0;
for (i = 0; i < blockSize; ++i)
    hashCode = (hashCode << 1) ^ block[i];
```